How to Route Traffic from One Target Group to Another in AWS ALB Based on Health Check Status?
My team manages two separate fleets in production:

Fleet A: Supports high customer critical use cases.
Fleet B: Supports less customer critical use cases.

During service duress, we have load shedding mechanism in Fleet A where when resources are under constrained, Fleet A shed the excess requests. In past, this has led to failure for critical use cases. To improve availability for customer critical use cases, we are exploring options to route traffic from Fleet A to Fleet B when Fleet A is under pressure or unhealthy.
Specifically, we want to know if ALB can dynamically route traffic from Target Group A (Fleet A) to Target Group B (Fleet B) based on the health check status of Target Group A. At present, both fleets are hosted under separate AWS Application Load Balancers (ALBs) and we want to enable Fleet B target group behind Fleet A AlB.
Requirements:

Fleet A (Target Group A) should receive traffic as long as it is healthy.
When Fleet A is unhealthy (e.g., fails health checks due to overload or errors like 5xx responses), ALB should automatically redirect traffic to Fleet B (Target Group B).
The health check should ideally consider specific error codes, like 503.

I am looking for guidance on:

Whether this can be achieved with AWS ALB and health checks.
How to set up listener rules to route traffic based on the health status of Target Group A.


Here’s a diagram of what we’re trying to achieve:


       +------------------+
       |   Client Traffic  |
       +------------------+
                |
                v
    +------------------------+
    |  AWS Application Load   |
    |       Balancer (ALB)    |
    +------------------------+
         /          \
        v            v
  +------------+  +------------+
  | Target     |  | Target     |
  | Group A    |  | Group B    |
  | (Fleet A)  |  | (Fleet B)  |
  +------------+  +------------+
        |
        v
  (Fails Health Check)
        |
        v
  +----------------+
  | Route Traffic  |
  | to Target Group|
  | B (Fleet B)    |
  +----------------+

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
The other alternative is that we build the capability on service java client which can also redirect traffic b/w both fleets. However, we would want to reduce the changes on client side, limiting any potential change in future.
